# Vim change color of text inside double curly brackets

Tags: vim, pattern-matching

I want to change the color of the text inside double curly brackets

like this **{{ a + b }}**, but so far this is the only thing I have been able to achieve:

```
syn match parens /[{}]/
hi parens ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

which is not exactly what I want as with it I can just change the color of the brackets
and if I try this it doesn't work at all

```
/{([^}]+)}}/
```

How can I properly write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more used to "magic" regex in vim (by adding the `\v` prefix) so I will write my example using them but you can easily translate to other types of regex supported by vim (see `:help magic`).

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you can achieve what you want with the following rule:

```
syntax match parens "\v\{\{.{-}\}\}"
highlight parens ctermfg=red guifg=red
```

This regex matches **{{ these sort of syntax }}** with any character inside the braces because of the `.`. The syntax `{-}` is equivalent to `*` except that vim tries to match the smallest number of characters between **{{** and **}}**. So that you don't match **{{ some }} example {{ text }}** but **{{ some }}** example **{{ text }}**. You can change the `.` if you want to be more specific about what you can match inside **{{** and **}}**.

Comment: That's perfect! Can I do this except for the pipe char always inside the brackets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're refering to. You want to highlight every character inside **{{** **}}** except `|` ? In that case use: `syntax match parens "\v\{\{.{-}\}\}" contains=pipe` and `syntax match pipe "\v\|" contained containedin=parens` with a different highlight rule for pipe and parens.